# Using draggable for fullcalendar without es6 and import

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using fullcalendar the non-es6 way, quite honestly because the bundled file was so large it was crashing stuff. Anyway, so I have loaded all the js files manually and all is well. Now I am trying to use Draggable. On the docs https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging it only shows you how to import Draggable from the interaction plugin. I have the interaction plugin up and running as I can drag events around on the calendar no problem, in fact I am editing bookings in Woo Bookings from them as they are dropped. I am now trying to drag resources from outside the calendar into the calendar and create bookings from them. I am getting `Plugin file not loaded for draggable` error in console, and of course `Uncaught ReferenceError: Draggable is not defined`

Here is my code

````
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        plugins: [ 'resourceTimeline', 'interaction' ],
        eventOverlap: false,
        resourceGroupField: 'groupID',
        resourceGroupText: 'groupText',
        defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        nowIndicator: true,
        droppable: true,
        defaultDate: currDate,
        eventRender: function(info) {
            $(info.el).find('.fc-content').attr("id", "event-" + info.event.id);
        },
        eventClick: function(info) {
            info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
            jQuery.colorbox({
                href: wsccAppVars.standardajax,
                data: {
                    action: 'fullcal_get_booking',
                    booking_id: info.event.id,
                    resource_id: info.event.resourceId
                }
            })
        },
        themeSystem: 'standard',
        editable: true,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable: false,
        resources: fcresources,
        resourceColumns: [{
            labelText: 'Lagoon',
            field: 'lname'
        }, {
              labelText: 'Product',
              field: 'pname'
          }], 
        eventSources: [{
              url: wsccAppVars.adminajax, // use the `url` property
              color: 'yellow',    // an option!
              textColor: 'black'  // an option!
        }],
        eventDrop: function(info) {
            //console.log(info);
            var data = {
                booking_id: info.event.id,
                resource_id: info.newResource.id,
                protect: $("#calendar").data('cal-protect'),
                action:  'wbsc_cal_booking_change'
            }
            //console.log(data);
            $.post(wbscAppVars.standardajax, data, function(response) {
                $("#calendar_messages").text(response.return_message)
                if (!response.success) {
                    info.revert();
                }
            })
        }
    });
    containerEl = document.getElementById('draggable_resources');
    new Draggable(containerEl, {
        itemSelector: '.draggable_resource'
    });

    calendar.render();```
````

Comment: From the documentation link you gave above (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging), go to the Live Demo which is linked a few lines down (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo) and then click on the CodePen link in the top corner. Being a CodePen, everything is imported using script tags instead of import statements. Then you'll see how to do it - it's just a property of the interaction class. Did you take a look at the demo at all?

Comment: Yeah I did, but not until after I posted this. I got sorted. Thx